# Jmeter: variable scope - How to use different random value for the same request

Tags: variables, scope, jmeter

I'm willing to use 2 variables for random values with the same request.

I defined both in User Parameters as follows: `var1=${__Random(1,100)}; var2=${__Random(1000,2000)}` (Also I checked: Update once per iteration)

I have the requests:

```
Request1: GET user/${var1} 
Request2: GET user/${var2}
```

During run-time, when it gets to request2 `var2` equals `var1`!
How do I fix that?

Comment: you mean to say `var2` is equal to `var1` value? i.e, from 1-100?

Answer (score 2):

Well, User Parameters is a [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) so you should put it as a child of your HTTP Request in order to get correct behavior. You can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to validate variables values (see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details)

[image: JMeter Debug Sampler]

I would recommend discarding this User Parameters and injecting the __Random() function directly into your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler Path like

- `/user/${__Random(1,100,var1)}`
- `/user/${__Random(1000,2000,var2)}`

This is a simpler way to generate random numbers and get them stored into JMeter Variables.

Comment: Ah, thank you, it worked correctly when I injected the random function directly into the HTTP Request sampler, as you recommended. Thanks again.